# How to remove carriage returns and new lines on all the columns in a table using Postgresql?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am  trying to see if there is any way to remove carriage and new lines from all the varchar columns in a table using one statement.

I know that we can do this for a single column using something like below

```
select regexp_replace(field, E'[\\n\\r]+', ' ', 'g' )
```

In that case I need have one for every column, which I don't want to do unless there is any easy way.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this either creating a plpgsql function to execute dynamic SQL, or directly run it via DO, as the following example (replace `my_table` with the name of your table`):

```
do $$declare _q text; _table text = '<mytable>';
begin
  select 'update '||attrelid::regclass::text||E' set\n'||
         string_agg('  '||quote_ident(attname)||$q$ = regexp_replace($q$||quote_ident(attname)||$q$, '[\n\r]+', ' ', 'g')$q$, E',\n' order by attnum)
  into _q
  from pg_attribute 
  where attnum > 0 and atttypid::regtype::text in ('text', 'varchar') 
  group by attrelid
  having attrelid = _table::regclass;

  raise notice E'Executing:\n\n%', _q;

  -- uncomment this line when happy with the query:
  -- execute _q;
end;$$;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this.